# Limit view of a user to only their own items in list WITHOUT user permissions in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, permissions, view

I'd like to be able to create a view for a list in which a user can see only those items that he/she creates. The caveat is that there are other parts of my site in which the user CAN view items that other users have created so I can't just adjust the Item-Level user permissions to only allow reading their own items because that will prevent the views at the other parts of the site from rendering properly.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions!

Comment: Can this also be used for show only created by specific multiple users? Do not want to show only items by [Me] but also of users 1, 2 and 3 for example, thus grouping list view by a specific group.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know you can do this in 2010 but cannot remember on 2007.  If you go to list settings and into Advanced Settings there is an option there to only allow users to see and/or edit their own items.  If you set this to only being able to edit their own but can see all then you can use a filter where Created By = [Me] on the views you want to control.

Comment: This is correct -- thanks so much! (I'd vote your answer up but Stackexchange wants me to have more reputation).

Comment: The important bit is you are sorted :)

Comment: [Me] does the trick for me also

Answer (score 0):

Restricting user to read items created by users have impact on rules. Rules are deleted and cannot be setup unless we restore the permission